# How can i log on this website with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I try to log on this website `https://www.extron.fr/home/login?ReturnUrl=/` with puppeteer but it doesn't work. Inputs ID change every time i reload page so i cant use them as selector...

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
async function login() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1200, height: 720 });
    await page.goto('https://www.extron.fr/home/login?ReturnUrl=/');
    await page.waitForNavigation();
    await page.type('.form-control email', 'test');
    await page.type('.form-control pr-5 password', 'test');
    await page.click('body > div > div > div.sign-in-window.modal--signin.shadow > form > fieldset > button');
    await page.waitForNavigation();
}
login();
```

Comment: The website changes the ID's of its elements because it does not want you to do the exact thing you do. It does not want anyone to automate login. You can however work around this, by using partial id selectors or other attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your selector is wrong. The classname .email needs a dot.

Instead of this,

```
.form-control email
```

You need this,

```
.form-control.email
```

Final code should be like this,

```
await page.type('.form-control.email', 'test');
await page.type('.form-control.pr-5.password', 'test');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector by tag name and attributes, eg.:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

;(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, devtools: true });
    const page = (await browser.pages())[0]
    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0)
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1200, height: 720 })
    await page.goto('https://www.extron.fr/home/login?ReturnUrl=/')
    await page.waitForSelector('button[type="submit"]')
    await page.type('input[type="email"]', 'your.email@address.com')
    await page.type('input[type="password"]', 'A_SecretPassword123@#$~!')
    await page.click('button[type="submit"]')
    await page.waitForSelector('alert>strong', { visible: true, timeout: 0 })
    await browser.close()
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried with this code and it works ! Thanks for help guys

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
function run () {
    return new Promise(async (reject) => {
        try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });;
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.setViewport({ width: 1200, height: 720 });
            await page.goto('https://www.extron.fr/home/login?ReturnUrl=/');
            await page.type('.email', 'test')
            await page.type('.password', 'test')
            await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
        } catch (e) {
            return reject(e);
        }
    })
}
run().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```